# How to re-install network

Tags: 12.04, networking

I had an issue with my realtek network drivers and r8168. So I followed many guides on how to fix this and I installed and compiled the latest drivers from realtek, however, in the end I still had the same issues. My problem now is that the driver is totally screwed somehow. I tried re-installing it, tried taking in on and off the blacklist but it seems nothing I try works.

So I need a way to completely reinstall and reconfigure the network in ubuntu. If I can uniinstall the network component (Lan cable / ipv4) and reinstall it that would be great.

Any ideas ?

bte - I'm using a 3G connection for the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depens on what exactly did the realtek-driver so to your system.I guess the driver did install itself into the modules directory of your kernel. In this case you can reinstall the kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Another option is that the driver did install itself into the update-directory in the kernel:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/...
```

Here you can simply delete the module from that directory.

To find out where the driver is located use:

```
modinfo "Name of the kernel module"
```

Comment: Thx , this worked. To be honesy , my kernel was on 35 so I updated to 37. I still have an issue with the driver not working as it should but at leasy my internet is working. Im thinking of installing a non realtek network card.